# Update same label after setting timer GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want to update a label after every 5s and it should be the only label in the RootLayoutPanel.Currently it adds a new label after every 5s but i want the same label to be updated.Can you suggest a method.Thanks

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use Timer to repeat after 5 sec.

Here is code:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;

final Label label=new Label("Hello ");
Timer timer=new Timer(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        label.setText("Hello "+Math.random()*100);
    }

};
timer.scheduleRepeating(5000);
RootPanel.get().add(label);
```